# How can I automatically login on a tty and execute a script

Tags: linux, boot, tty

I have installed android x86 on my desktop.When i select the boot option of android in the grub,it goes to tty8 and then I go to tty1 using alt+F1,and then login into my Ubuntu user account (where my android images are stored)run a start-up shell script which loads android.
What i need is to automate these processes i.e. when i select the boot option of android,it should go to tty1 and execute the shell script automatically without having to log in.

Is this feasible?
If so,how?

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'mingetty' to autologin.

```
sudo apt-get install mingetty
```

Then edit /etc/init/tty1.conf

Change the line saying

```
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

Into

```
exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin root --noclear tty1
```

Note that this automatically logs root in, maybe you want a different user.
As for automatically running shell scripts: you can put your (or call it from) script in ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Hey thanks,that worked.To automatically run the script,if the shell script is put in ~/.bash_profile,then everything will work fine if i log into android,but if i log in to Ubuntu,then also it will try to run the script(please correct me if i am wrong), which i don't want.I want to run the script only when the boot option selected is android.Is there any way using which the script can get which is the boot option selected?

Comment: I dont understand. From what I read was that: you always boot into Ubuntu which in turn starts Android?

Or do you use a bootloader to select either Ubuntu or Android?

Comment: i use grub to select Ubuntu or Android, i think i have mentioned it in my question 'When i select the boot option of android in the grub...'

Comment: Yes, but it is confusing as it says you select Android, but log in to Ubuntu. Then you run a script to load Android.. If this is the case then what is the difference between Ubuntu and Android in grub?